Get certain value from column with varying row index in Pandas
I am using Pandas to process numerous Excel files and I need to extract certain values from columns. The position within the column (the row) may vary but the name of the column remains the same throughout the files as does the start of the desired value which always starts with 'K_'.
The only way I can come up with is iterating over the files, creating dataframes, getting the unique values of each column and then with an if-statement get the value that starts with 'K_'.
That solution works fine but I am certain there is an easier and more elegant way to achieve the same result.
Here is a brief working example of my problem:
import pandas as pd

file1 = {'Col1' : ['', '', 'K_ABC', '', '', '']}
file2 = {'Col1' : ['', 'K_DEF', '', '', '', '']}
file3 = {'Col1' : ['', '', '', 'K_GHI', '', '']}

files = [file1, file2, file3]

for foo in files:
    df = pd.DataFrame(foo)
    values = df['Col1'].unique()
    for val in values:
        if val.startswith('K_'):
            print(val)

The other rows can be anything like empty strings, NaN, other strings, etc. so just filtering out the empty strings is not going to cut it.

Rather than use explicit loops, take advantage of pandas' vectorization (Cf. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/dsintro.html#vectorized-operations-and-label-alignment-with-series):
for foo in files:
    df = pd.DataFrame(foo)
    # filter on the rows where the Col1 value begins with K_
    filt = df['Col1'].str.startswith('K_')
    # apply the filter to the dataframe and retrieve the values
    vals = df[filt]['Col1'].unique()
    print(vals)


Perfect, I was looking for exactly something like that! Thanks a lot!

For some files I am getting this error: ValueError: Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values. What can I do about this? @Mark

@Kai find the indices for which filt has NA/NaN values, then find those entries in Col1. That should give you a clue.
